# Safely dispose within .net finalizer

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable, finalizer

I wanted a way to break the `IDisposable` chain where some nested class that you suddenly depend on now implements `IDisposable` and you don't want that interface to ripple up the layers of your composite. *Basically, I have weak subscriptions to `IObservable<T>`'s via ['SubscribeWeakly()'](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2012/03/weak-events-in-net-easy-way.html) that I want to clean up when I go away to not leak the wrapper instances just in case the `Observable` never fires. That was the motivation, but I use it for other stuff as well.*

Another post had a similar problem, and the [answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12142559/dispose-a-list-of-idisposables-in-the-finalizer#answer-12142641) basically stated that you can still access the disposables in your finalizer. However, you're not guaranteed what order the finalizers are run in, so disposing might be problematic.

Therefore, I needed a way to guarantee that the disposable is kept alive so I can call `Dispose()` in my finalizer. So I looked at `GCHandle`, which allows C++ to hold (and keep alive) managed objects by pulling them and their aggregates into an application handle to keep them alive until the handle is free'd and the composite lifetime returns to the control of .NET's memory manager. Coming from C++, I thought behavior similar to `std::unique_ptr` would be good so I came up with something similar to `AutoDisposer`.

```cs
public class AutoDisposer
{
    GCHandle _handle;

    public AutoDisposer(IDisposable disposable)
    {
        if (disposable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        _handle = GCHandle.Alloc(disposable);
    }

    ~AutoDisposer()
    {
        try 
        {
            var disposable = _handle.Target as IDisposable;
            if (disposable == null) return;
            try 
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
            finally 
            {
                _handle.Free();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

In the class that needs to dispose resources when it goes away, I would just assign a field like `_autoDisposables = new AutoDisposer(disposables)`. This `AutoDisposer` would then get cleaned up by the garbage collector around them same time the containing class does. However, I'm wondering what the issues would be with this technique. Right now I can think of the following:

- Extra overhead on the garbage collector by having finalizers
- Extra overhead of .NET having to pull out items from managed memory into application handles and returning them
- Not unit testable (I can't seem to predict when the resource gets returned to .NET for memory management.)

Therefore, I use it sparingly when implementing `IDisposable` isn't too much of a burden, if I need to deterministically call `Dispose()`, or etc.

Does anybody see any other issues? Is this technique even valid?

Comment: Simple answer: remove all destructors (Finalizers). Forget about this.

Comment: _I needed a way to guarantee that the disposable is kept alive so I can call `Dispose()`_  - is turning things upside down.

Comment: By the time you're inside *your* finalizer, the `IDisposable` (if implemented correctly) may have already run *its* finalizer and done as much cleanup as it can be reasonably expected to do within a finalizer. Your calling `Dispose` on it can't possibly help by this stage.

Comment: I guess the problem is that disposing a subscription is really just performing a managed action (no unmanaged resources to worry about here). The action is to unregister a listener (or listener wrapper instance in my case) to an event. This won't happen if the event never triggers and `Dispose` is never called. So I have to call `Dispose` from my finalizer. I was keeping it alive to ensure there are no issues when I call `Dispose` (dangling null pointers, race conditions, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you might've misunderstood `IDispoable` - the typical pattern on an `IDisposable` object is loosely:

```
void Dispose() { Dispose(true); }

void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        // Free managed resources
    }
    // always free unmanaged resources
}

~Finalizer() { Dispose (false); }
```

Because the finalizer should always handle unmanaged resources, if you wait for it to run (which will be at some point in the future when memory constraints trigger the garbage collection, or it's triggered manually), you shouldn't leak. If you want to be **deterministic** about when those resources are freed, then you will have to expose `IDispoable` down your class hierarchy.

Comment: Certainly proper use of `Dispose` is desirable.  The question, as I see it, is how to limit the damage done by code which fails to call `Dispose`.  For example, one might have a logging class with a "log tentatively" function that will buffer data that should be logged in case of failure.  In case of success it will discard that buffer and log a success; otherwise it will log the failure along with the buffer contents.  If such an object is abandoned, one may wish to have it output its buffer, along with an entry saying it was abandoned, before the log file gets closed.

Comment: I think I understand Dispose pattern. @supercat portrayed my intent. I'm trying to limit the damage done by code that fails to call `Dispose`. There are no unmanaged resources to deal with. Dispose is performing an action (removing an event wrapper from an `IObservable` event in Rx) that won't happen if I don't call `Dispose`. If the event source goes away, I'm OK. If it doesn't, I need to unregister my weak (weak meaning it has no strong reference to me) subscription wrapper to avoid leaking it. So I just need a safe way of calling `Dispose` when I go away without implementing `IDisposable`

Comment: Thing is, that Dispose is about clearing up resources deterministically. If it's got to the point of your finalizer being called, you *could* already have been freed by then, as the GC thinks nothing important references you - by defining a Finalizer, you'll force the object to hang around a bit longer, whilst it sits in the Finalizer queue.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to design classes so that they can coordinate their finalization behavior with each other.  For example, an object could accept a constructor parameter of type `Action(bool)`, and specify that if non-null it will be called as the first step of `Dispose(bool)` [the backing field could be be read with `Interlocked.Exchange(ref theField, null)` to ensure the delegate gets invoked at most once].  If a class that e.g. encapsulates a file included such a feature, and was wrapped in a class which encapsulates the file with extra buffering, the file would notify the buffering class that it was about to close, and the buffering class could thus ensure that all necessary data was written.  Unfortunately, such a pattern is not common in the framework.

Given the lack of such a pattern, the only way that a class which encapsulates a buffered file could ensure that it would manage to write out its data if it's abandoned, without the file getting closed before it can do so, would be to persist a static reference somewhere to the file (perhaps using a static instance of `ConcurrentDictionary(bufferedWrapper, fileObject)`) and ensure that when it is cleaned up, it will destroy that static reference, write its data to the file, and then close the file.  Note that this approach should only be used if the wrapper object keeps exclusive control over the object that it wraps, and it requires extreme attention to detail.  Finalizers have many weird corner cases, it's hard to handle them all properly, and any failure to handle obscure corner cases correctly is likely to result in Heisenbugs.

**PS** Continuing along the `ConcurrentDictionary` approach, if you're using something like events your main concerns are apt to be (1) ensuring that if an object is abandoned the events don't hold a reference to anything "big"; (2) ensuring that the number of abandoned objects in the `ConcurrentDictionary` cannot grow without bound.  The first issue can be handled by ensuring that there is no "strong" reference path from an event to any significant "forest" of interconnected objects; if a superfluous subscription only holds references to objects totalling 100 bytes or so, and they'll get cleared up if any of the events ever fire, even a thousand abandoned subscriptions would represent a very minor problem [provided the number is bounded].  The second issue can be handled by having each subscription requests poll some items in the dictionary (either on a per-request or amortized basis) to see if they're abandoned and clean them up if so.  If some events are abandoned and never fire, and if no new events of that type are ever added, those events may stick around indefinitely but they'll be harmless.  The only way the events could be significantly harmful would be if they held reference to big objects (which can be avoided using weak references), an unbounded number of events could be added and abandoned without ever getting cleaned up (which won't happen if adding new events causes abandoned ones to get cleaned up), or if such events could waste CPU time continuously (which won't happen if the first attempt to fire them after the objects that cared about them are gone would cause them to get cleaned up).

Comment: Wouldn't my GCHandle guarantee the disposable is kept alive to safely call dispose on it upon finalization? This is what is used for C++ to guarantee managed objects are kept alive by native code. Problems could come up on application shutdown. However, they don't seem to for C++ so I assume Microsoft has worked that issue out (maybe .NET is already shut down, so the application handle simply free's the memory, and buttons up any unmanaged resources like normal).

Comment: I thought about going the ConcurrentDictionary approach with a thread that would execute ever so often to clean it out (call dispose on items tied to the lifetime of other items - using weak references). There would be no finalizer to have to worry about disposing things at application shutdown. However, that would require an extra thread, a "global" variable (the dictionary), and settling on an application-wide timing for cleaning it out. The `AutoDisposer` approach seemed more self-contained.